# Issue using PhpStorm along with WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I just started using PhpStorm and WebStorm and I am working on the same directory with both. The problem is that each time I switch between windows, I am prompted for reloading the project because `workspace.xml` changes. I really don't have any clue how to get over this. Did anyone had the same issue? What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not use both WebStorm and PhpStorm at the same time on the same system and project. Note that PhpStorm already includes all the WebStorm features, so you don't need WebStorm if you have PhpStorm.

Comment: Oh.. well that's good news. It really is the first time I open any of them, I didn't know the specific features of each. Thanks!

Comment: they should state that more clearly on their site imo